# Unable to clear activities when launch new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I unable to clear activities in activitystack and check the below snippet

**Java :**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

**Manifest**

```
       <activity
        android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppHomeTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"/>
```

what's would be reason?

Comment: Thanks to all and I have fixed , It's logical issue on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code to solved your issue.

Also add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and try.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

Comment: Read the Doc for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`.